# Adicionar e remover itens favoritos com session php e ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Fala pessoal,

estou precisando implementar um recurso no meu site, que vai permitir que o usuário possa selecionar os imóveis do seu gosto clicando em um botão "adicionar aos favoritos", e clicando novamente ele possa remover esse item. Eu sei que posso usar sessions php e ajax, porém não sei exatamente como fazer. Alguém poderia me dá uma ideia ou exemplo dessa aplicação?

Exemplo desse recurso econtra-se nesse site: http://www.maximobiliaria.com.br/site_2014/web/vendas

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você quer saber como fazer uma cesta de compras, então eu sugiro que vc faça algo assim:

```
session_start();

class Imoveis
{

private $favorites = [];

    public function addFavorites($product)
    {
      if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
          $this->favorites = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
          $this->favorites[] = $product;
      } else {
        $this->favorites[] = $product;
      }
     $this->setCart();
    }

    public function removeFavorites($product)
    {
      if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
          $collection = unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
      } else {
          $collection = $this->favorites;
      }
         if (count($collection)) {
            foreach ($collection as $key => $productList) {
                  if ($productList == $product) {
                      unset($collection[$key]);
                  }
            }
            $this->favorites = array_values($collection);
         }
        $this->setCart();
    }

    public function setCart()
    {
      $_SESSION['cart'] = serialize($this->favorites);
    }

    public function getCart()
    {
      return unserialize($_SESSION['cart']);
    }

}
//instancia o objeto
$imoveis = new Imoveis();

//adiciona
$imoveis->addFavorites('casa 1');

//remove
$imoveis->removeFavorites('casa 1');

//exibe a lista
$imv =  $imoveis->getCart();

foreach ($imv as $imovel) {
      echo $imovel . nl2br("\n");
}
```

Comment: Fala meu amigo, apesar de não dominar OO, vou tentar implementar essa class. Vou te dá um retorno pra dizer se obtive sucesso.